# Why is Bower's search functionality case-insensitive?

Tags: javascript, bower

I just registered a bower package as "Keypress". It does not show up when searching for "keypress". Is this a bug or maybe an oversight?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the fix was never [deployed](https://github.com/bower/registry/issues/15).

Comment: Update: seems it was eventually deployed? See comment: https://github.com/bower/registry/issues/15#issuecomment-50229002